# How to find out which marker was clicked from an array of google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback

I have an array of marker objects `markers`. I then use a for loop to add event listeners to them. However, I can't seem to figure out how to determine WHICH of the markers was clicked.

Here is the code I have now:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) //adds listener to all markers
 {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[i], "click", () =>
      {
            //need to get access to which marker was clicked
      }); 
 }
```

I've tried passing arguments to the arrow function, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? An arrow function is not necessary as long as the function can return the index of the correct marker.

Comment: if you make the callback a function rather than an arrow function, `this` will be the marker that was clicked

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventClosures).

Here is a working example:

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1)
  };

  var locations = [
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 'Marker 1', 'Infowindow content for Marker 1'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 1), 'Marker 2', 'Infowindow content for Marker 2'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 2), 'Marker 3', 'Infowindow content for Marker 3'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 0), 'Marker 4', 'Infowindow content for Marker 4'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1), 'Marker 5', 'Infowindow content for Marker 5'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2), 'Marker 6', 'Infowindow content for Marker 6']
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i][0],
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][1]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }

    })(marker, i));
  }
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: great answer, thanks, maybe you're interested in this very related bounty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449206/on-google-maps-api-load-infowindow-only-after-click